# How to copy and paste code while retaining the format

Tags: windows, copy-paste

This question may have been asked before but I was unable to find any solution.

When I browse and see some code that I would like to copy, I simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Most of the time this works fine, but in some cases (websites like StackOverflow and a few others), when I copy the code and paste it, it only comes on one line in Eclipse. I have tried pasting this code into Eclipse, then selecting all and then Auto Format but this doesn’t help either. I have also pasted the code into Komodo and Word with the same results. The code simply refuses to align itself.

Does anyone know any solution to this?

Comment: Does it copy all the code and 'consolidate' it on one line? If that is the case you might have a problem with line breaks.

Comment: Thats exactly what it does. Line break problem in word,komodo and eclipse - If so how would i change it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked:

Copy the code into a word document which will understand and format the line changes correctly, then copy the word document and paste it into Eclipse.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I use a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cofoco-code-format-and-co/lmfhiimgedfddgbghclbdmbpghojikop) called CoFoCo that formats and copies JavaScript/TypeScript code at the same time. It saves me from having to do a bunch of manual edits on big code blocks.

After installing it, I can:

- specify an optional Prettier config in the extension popup menu to set custom formatting options (how many spaces per tab, whether or not to add trailing commas, etc)
- highlight a code block on StackOverflow (or other site) and right click on it
- in the dropdown menu (with "Back", "Save as", and "Inspect" options) there is now a CoFoCo option. Clicking it will format the code block based on the Prettier config provided (or based a default config if none provided) and copy it to the clipboard.
- the code block that's then pasted into your editor or document should be formatted

Comment: Naming the plugin and explaining how to use it to solve this problem would go a long way towards making this an answer. Right now it is only a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144284)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really comfatable posting this as an answer since I did not test it and I rarely encounter the problem myself. However one the few occasions that I ran into these problems I could work around it by pasting into an editor which understands multiple forms of line ending. Usually I use vim for this, but I think both wordpad and notepad++ also work. This works as an occasional workaround. It is not what I consider a 'proper' solution

A bit of background to explain why this will work:

In the days of mechanical typewriters you typed all text on a single line. When you reached the end of that line you usually wanted to do two things:

1. Return the cariage head to the beginning of the line
2. Scroll the paper one line so the next text starts below it.

These are refered to as CR and LF. (Cariage Return and Line Feed).

Computers needed something similar. Most unix based systems used the linefeed. However windows decided to use both CR LF to mark the end of a line. To confuse things further Macintosh just used CR.

Comment: I used wordpad and it didnt work. Just for you to test, you can copy any code(must be in code brackets) on stack overflow(java preferably since xml seems to work okay in auto format in eclipse) and paste it into wordpad. It is completely disorganized.